# Datatable Javascript Library

Tags: javascript, datatable

Is there a JS datatable library that supports cell changes with callbacks to the database?

For instance: if I select cell A2 and modify it's contents, I want it to write back to the database.

Thanks

Comment: can´t you add a onchange event and apply change to db?

Comment: I suggest you to use x-editable plugin, with tags loaded from remote and activated on click only, not all together after load